# IIS Site application pool vs app application pool

Tags: iis, application-pool

I don't quite understand what is the difference between the app pool of the site and the application pool of the separate app.

I mean why do we need to specify app pool for the site ?

What is the difference between the "v4.0" and "No Manage Code" CLR Versions for the application pool of the site ?

For example we can specify "v4.0" for the site app pool and "No Manage Code" for the application pool of the separate app and it will work.

Comment: 1) Don't ask a bunch of questions altogether. That only messes things up. 2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#applications "In IIS 7 and above, each site must have an application which is named the root application, or default application." That's why the site also needs its application pool.

Comment: Thank you. What happens to the applications if the site app pool was stopped ? In case if applications and the site placed in different app pools.

Comment: Why not test the results on a machine?

Comment: I stopped the app pool of the site. And... The application is keep on running, accepting requests. That's really confusing.

Comment: Why can that be confusing? It clearly reveals that the application pools (root application of the site, and the other custom applications under the same site) are isolated from each other, which is expected for most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't quite understand what is the difference between the app pool of the site and the application pool of the separate app. I mean why do we need to specify app pool for the site ?

Application pools are used to separate sets of IIS worker processes that share the same configuration and application boundaries. Application pools are used to isolate our web application for better security, reliability, availability and performance, and they keep running without impacting each other.

The application pool is a collection of websites running as a single process, with a single identity. You can have multiple websites running under a single application pool, but you can not have a single website running in multiple application pools. Splitting websites over application pools allows more rigid security between the sites, as well as preventing one website from crashing if another one does. The benefit of combining multiple sites into a single application pool is to either share resources, or to leave a smaller server footprint on the server.

More information you can refer to this link: [Application Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753449(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> What is the difference between the "v4.0" and "No Manage Code" CLR Versions for the application pool of the site ?

"v4.0" is the version of .NET Framework, "No Manage Code" is the version of CLR, when you specify .NET CLR version as "v4.0" for an application pool, IIS loads into its worker processes some ASP.NET supporting libraries (like aspnet_isapi.dll for classic pipeline mode, and webengine4.dll for integrated mode). when you specify .NET CLR version as "No Manage Code", it means you only run non-ASP.NET 4.x and 2.x apps (PHP, ASP.NET Core and so on).